# jquery to loop through table, for each row and td concatonate values

Tags: jquery

I have a table with several rows. each row has a product field, a grade field and a family field.

There is then several checkboxes for each available size.

a row in the table looks like this:

```
<table class="authors-list" border=0 id="ordertable">
 <tr>
     <td style="font-size:10px;"><a class="deleteRow"> <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/assets/images/delete2.png" /></a></td>
     <td ><input type="text" id="product1" name="product1" class="rounded"/></td>
     <td ><input type="text" size='5' id="qty1" name="qty1" class="rounded"/></td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox"  id="h09_1" name="h09_1" class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_09" name="line_1_09" value="">
      <input type="text"  id="size_1_09" name="size_1_09" value="09">

    </td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox"  id="h12_1" name="h12_1" class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_12" name="line_1_12" value="">
      <input type="text"  id="size_1_12" name="size_1_12" value="12">
    </td> 
     <td class="tdcheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox"  id="h15_1" name="h15_1" class="rounded"/>
      <input type="text"  id="line_1_15" name="line_1_15" value="">
      <input type="text"  id="size_1_15" name="size_1_15" value="15">
    </td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="cubespercheck_1" id="cubespercheck_1" value="0" size=5></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="skufamily_1" id="skufamily_1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="skugrade_1" id="skugrade_1"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="continue" value="continue">
```

all fields will be hidden in end result besides the product field.

To give you a background, my product code looks like this:
3811460S5
38114 is the width and height
60 is the length
Cr is the grade.

What I want to happen is that when I click the button, jquery must loop through all tables cells. where there is a CHECKED checkbox AND product has been populated, jquery must join the fields as below:
skufamily(for row[skufamily])+length(from cell[size])+grade(from row[skugrade])

this result must populate the current td input `line`. so now each cell will have an exact sku (only if checked and product populated)

skufamily,size, and grade is prepopulated so just need the jquery to loop and join the fields.

here is a fiddle to play on. http://jsfiddle.net/QS56z/

I have tried the following concept but cant quite nail the code.

```
    function createcodes() {
$("table.authors-list").find('input[type="checkbox"][name^="h"]:checked').each(function () {
 if (<checkbox is checked>)
      document.getElementById(input[type="skufamily").value + 
      document.getElementById(input[type="size").value +
      document.getElementById(input[type="skugrade").value

        });
```

This is far from correct so if you can put me on the right path I'd appreciate it.

Thanks a million as always.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Thanks Limelights, I have updated the question with what I have but think I am on the wrong path... very much so... sorry new to jquery and coding in general.

Comment: No need to apologize for being a beginner, just make sure you read our FAQ before posting. FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Thanks Limelights, will adhere to this more going forward.

Comment: Cool beans, chief! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QS56z/19/).
I think this code should do it.

```
$("#continue").click(function(){
    $("table#ordertable > tbody > tr").each(function(){
        var productVal = $('td:eq(0) input', this).val();
        if(productVal.length > 0){
            //get the code portion
            var trimmedProductVal = productVal.substring(0, productVal.length - 2);
            var productCode = productVal.substring(productVal.length-2, productVal.length);
            //get the checked items
            $('td.tdcheckbox', this).each(function(){
                var currentCell = this;
                $("input[type='checkbox']:checked", this).each(function(){
                    //concatenate the value
                    var valueToSet = $('input[type="text"]:eq(1)', currentCell).val();
                    valueToSet = trimmedProductVal + valueToSet + productCode;
                    //set the text value
                    $('input[type="text"]:eq(0)', currentCell).val(valueToSet);
                });;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Impressive. thanks Terence, I'll need to work through that to understand it but works perfectly. Appreciate your efforts. Thanks again.