# jquery array of nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 2 columns. One column with a checkbox and another one with plain text. I would like to generate an object array with the the check state and the text. I can go tr after tr with this:

```
$('#divInfCambios .frozen-bdiv tr').each(function(i)
{ ... }
```

How can access to `td[1]`, check the state, and recover the text of `td[2]`?

I got the check state with:

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')
```

I need now how to access node 2 (`td[1]`) and grab the text.

Comment: can you show us the html structure of the table?

Comment: Hint: the right tool to use in your situation is `map()`, not `each()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169109/jquery-to-loop-through-table-for-each-row-and-td-concatonate-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//run through each row
$('#divInfCambios .frozen-bdiv tr').each(function (i, row) {

    var getInputByName = $(this).find('input[name="selection"]');
    if (getInputByName.is(':checked') ){

    }       
    // assuming you layout of the elements
    var tds = $(this).find('td');
    var getTdText = tds.eq(1).text();

});
```

Comment: Working nicely! Thanks for your quick answer Scor3keeper!